# Boosting specific cpu core (first one) and keep others at level so that first thread reach maximum frequency

Tags: cpu, boost

I have Ubuntu 22.04 running on amd epyc 7443p cpu 24 cores / 48 threads.
I need to run first core (zero) at maximum boost frequency that hardware allows, or at least higher than all others.
I have tried to do this with cpupower setting governor to performance for c 0, and set other 47 to conservative but all cores are running at somewhat same frequency and first one newer can get higher.